# Write $π = (3, 2, 5)(2, 5, 4)$ in “table” notation?

Tags: permutations

Isn't this impossible...? Because this permutation goes from 3 --> 2 ---> 5 ---> 3 according to the first cycle, but goes from 2 --> 5 ---> 4 ---> 2 according to the second cycle. So 5 can't go to 3 and 4.

Comment: What is table notation? Do you do the multiplication left to right?

Comment: It's where you write the permutations like I did with the arrow, except instead of 2--->5 you write 2 on top and 5 directly below that

Comment: Read it from right to left in terms of what each permutation does to a particular element.  $(3,2,5)(2,5,4) = \begin{pmatrix} 1&2&3&4&5\\ 1&3&2&5&4\end{pmatrix}$.  This is because look at what happens to $2$.  After the first cycle it gets changed to five, and while five it gets changed to a three by the second permutation, so altogether $2$ gets mapped to $3$.  Similarly for the other entries.

Comment: Chris, you really have to tell which convention you assume for the product of permutations, as both are used (left-to-right and right-to-left). JMoravitz and probablyme answers are both correct.

Comment: I believe it's left-to-right. Sorry, I'm still not very familiar with permutations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you do multiplication left to right, then
$$(3\quad2\quad5)(2\quad5\quad4) = 
\begin{pmatrix}1&2&3&4&5\\
1&5&2&4&3
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1&2&3&4&5\\
1&5&3&2&4
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}1&2&3&4&5\\
1&4&5&2&3\end{pmatrix}$$